# How do I make JavaScript tell PHP that it is receiving a array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make javascript pass the values of the array of images to php so that I can save them in my database but I can't seem to do this.

what I have in the snippet is this

```
$('.image-upload-btn').on('click', function() {
  var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.style.display = 'none'
  $('html body').append(input);
  input.click();
  input.onchange = function() {
    $('.image-upload-btn').css('background-image', 'url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png)');
  }
});
```

but I want to make it so that I does this:

```
$('.image-upload-btn').on('click', function() {
  var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.name = 'myFile[]'; //this
  input.id = 'myFile[]';   //this
  input.multiple = 'multiple'; //and this
  input.style.display = 'none'
  $('html body').append(input);
  input.click();
  input.onchange = function() {
    $('.image-upload-btn').css('background-image', 'url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png)');
  }
});
```

this was added:

```
  input.name = 'myFile[]'; //this
  input.id = 'myFile[]';   //this
  input.multiple = 'multiple'; //and this
```

where I can add the name of the input and it's value. But when I press a submit button the images do not get saved.

```js
$('.image-upload-btn').on('click', function() {
  var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.style.display = 'none'
  $('html body').append(input);
  input.click();
  input.onchange = function() {
    $('.image-upload-btn').css('background-image', 'url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png)');
  }
});
```

```css
.image-upload-btn {
  background-image: url('http://bread.pp.ua/n/settings_g.svg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='image-upload-btn'></div>
```

```js
$('.image-upload-btn').on('click', function() {
  var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.style.display = 'none'
  $('html body').append(input);
  input.click();
  input.onchange = function() {
    $('.image-upload-btn').css('background-image', 'url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png)');
  }
});
```

Comment: you'd be better off with a single `<input type="file" name="foo[]" multiple>`  than multiple sepearate file inputs.

Comment: the thing is I don't want to show the bar for file upload. Rather show a image as a button that has an action of the file upload.

Comment: upload via ajax, you mean?

Comment: I don't know how I would do this. ajax or as I have it in my snippet @MarcB